# Express app is trying (and failing) to connect to a websocket

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a react / node app on Heroku.  The site is up here: https://rift-website-3.herokuapp.com/.

I'm getting a console error that the site is trying to connect to a websocket. Here is the error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://rift-website-3.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/info?t=1471044468173'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I'm a bit new to `Express`, why is my app trying to connect to a websocket?

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Which loads **index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'>
    </div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which loads **index.js**:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './containers/App';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Which loads **App.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../reducers/index';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import { fetchCurrentUserIfNeeded } from '../actions/auth';

// Main SCSS that imports the others.
import '../css/app.scss';

// Containers
import Home from './Home';

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      appInitialized: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    store.dispatch(fetchCurrentUserIfNeeded());

    // TODO: I think this may not be performant.
    // http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe
    store.subscribe(() => {
      if (store.getState().auth.initialCheckComplete) {
        this.setState({ appInitialized: true });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render');

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your `index.html` trying to connect to that address over http?

Comment: I don't believe so.  Going to add the "react" tag and post my app.js file

Comment: Including the page that's giving you the issue on load would be important.